# Does P = NP in Cellular Automata of Hyperbolic Spaces?

Tags: complexity-theory, automata, p-vs-np, cellular-automata

I read a few years ago in [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933153040) that [NP problems are tractable in the space of cellular automata in the hyperbolic plane](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030439759900328X). What does this mean? Does `P = NP` according to these books/papers?

Some excerpts from the paper:

> It is well known that if we have binary trees at our disposal “for free”, it is possible to solve NP-problems in polynomial time, see [14, 5]. However, it is not immediate to implement binary tree algorithms in the pentagrid, and the goal of this section is to indicate how one can proceed.

From my understanding, the [P = NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem) problem is looking for polynomial-time algorithms to solve complicated problems. From my cursory glance through the books and papers, it seems to suggest that he has solved the problem. What am I missing?

[Here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/57b8/bb57d9e8c8e699ccb54d4fb98c54f1a417d0.pdf) is another paper, titled *In Some Curved Spaces, We Can Solve NP-Hard Problems in Polynomial Time: Towards Matiyasevich's Dream*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The P vs. NP problem is a question about Turing machines $T$, because the complexity classes P and NP are defined in terms of these theoretical machines. Let's call these classes $P_T$ and $NP_T$ from now on. The paper introduces a new theoretical computation machine   $H$ that has associated classes $P_H$ (runs in polynomial time on the hyperbolic cellular automaton) and $NP_H$ (runs in non-deterministic polynomial time on the hyperbolic cellular automaton).

The first step in this paper is a proof that the 3SAT problem, a well known $NP_T$-complete problem, can be solved in polynomial time on this machine, i.e. this problem lies in $P_H$. Next, they show any polynomial time reduction on a Turing machine can be performed in polynomial time on their hyperbolic automaton. Since 3SAT is $NP_T$-complete, any $NP_T$ instance can be reduced to a 3SAT instance in polynomial time (on $T$ by definition, so also on $H$ by their lemma) and then be solved by solving 3SAT in poly-time, both on the hyperbolic automaton. In other words, the main result of this paper (Theorem 1) can be written as $NP_T \subseteq P_H$ in our notation. This does not give a solution to the P vs. NP problem, because that would need to relate the classes $NP_T$ and $P_T$.

Note that the authors include some remarks on the P vs. NP problem in section 4.2, where they claim their result is evidence for P$\neq$NP (!):

> A third direction consists of the new light shed on the P=NP question in the
> ordinary settings. As the hyperbolic space has properties which are very different from the properties of the euclidean space, in particular, it has many more directions, would not that be a hint favorable to prove that P$\neq$NP in euclidean conditions? It seems that
> for the last ten years the works in the field of complexity incline people to believe
> more in P$\neq$NP. Apparently, the present result also belongs to that trend.

Comment: Is this at all exciting, or has this been broadly known for decades? Haha.

Comment: @LancePollard What has been known, exactly? That there are "reasonable" computational models $X$ for which $NP_T\subseteq P_X$? In the quote in your question, it is claimed that reference [14] gives an example of that, which is from 1986.

Comment: I guess I just remember hearing some hyperbole around P = NP and so saw this paper and thought maybe they did something about it and no one noticed. I've seen other papers that went ignored.

Comment: For reference this is where I was coming from: _"Theorem 1 (Margenstern–Morita). NP-problems can be solved in polynomial time in the space of cellular automata in the hyperbolic plane."_ from [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397502006606).